# Jquery .load() - How to execute Javascript in original document from loaded content

Tags: jquery, onload

I have a document that loads some content into a div with JQuery's .load() function. That loaded content then tries to execute Javascript from the original document. This fails, possibly for obvious reasons (I am a Javascript novice). Here is simplified code that illustrates my problem.

test.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        background: #ccc;
        margin: 15px;
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #666;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="loader">Load content into box below</a>
    <div id="loadbox"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

            $('a.loader').click(function() {
                $('#loadbox').load('loadme.html');
            });

            $('a.alerter').click(function() {
                alert("I've been clicked!");
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

loadme.html:

```
<a href="#" class="alerter">Click me</a> for an alert.
```

The alert is triggered if I put the Javascript in the loaded content, but I have a large block of Javascript that I want to use with more than one div full of loaded content and I don't want to keep loading the Javascript. Is there a way to access the Javascript in the original HTML from the loaded content? I don't have a firm understanding of what order things are executed in, especially when I have loaded content into the page. Maybe this is my opportunity to learn! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DYou should use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) because you are adding an element to the document (this is for jQuery < 1.7)

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

        $('a.loader').click(function() {
            $('#loadbox').load('loadme.html');
        });

        $('a.alerter').live("click", function() {
            alert("I've been clicked!");
        });

    });
```

for jQuery > 1.7 you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and delegate the handler to the body

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

        $('a.loader').click(function() {
            $('#loadbox').load('loadme.html');
        });

        $('body').on("click", "a.alerter", function() {
            alert("I've been clicked!");
        });

    });
```

Comment: This is really helpful. It definitely works with my example. The real file is a little complex, but if it works it will be worth it. And getting to work might just learn me a lesson. Thank you!

Comment: OK, it turned out my actual problem had nothing to do with this (although the example I created for this question did). But I learned something irregardless. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because the dom u load is not here and the script can't not find it ; , plz try it :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.loader').click(function () {
        $('#loadbox').load('loadme.html', function () {
            $('a.alerter').click(function () {
                alert("I've been clicked!");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: U can think simple , we need a paper frist , after that we can write. U need place a function with this paper when it has been loaded.

Comment: Thank you. The input from both of you helped me wrap my mind around what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$('a.alerter').click(function() {
    alert("I've been clicked!");
});
```

With

```
$("#loadbox").delegate( "a.alerter", "click", function() {
    alert("I've been clicked!");
});
```

This will delegate the event to `#loadbox`, which exists, so it will work as long as `#loadbox` exists.